# Spring Cloud : API Gateway routing not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, api-gateway

I am working with Spring Cloud. I have four services in my spring boot application `college-service`, `student-service`, `eureka-server` and `api-gateway`. I am trying to call `college-service` and `student-service` with API Gateway. While I'm calling My `college-service` from API Gateway that's work fine but `student-service` is not working. While I am trying to get `student-serivice`, I get error `404` not found. I'm new guy in Spring Cloud. Here down is my code.

*Here down is my urls, Where in last url I get 404*

| URL | Status |
| --- | --- |
| http://localhost:9001/college/CLG01 | 200 OK |
| http://localhost:9002/college/student/CLG01 | 200 OK |
| http://localhost:9003/college/CLG01 | 200 OK |
| http://localhost:9003/college/student/CLG01 | 400 Not Found |

#### Colleger Service

*Entity*

```
public class College {
    private String clgId;
    private String clgName;
    private String clgCity;

    List<Student> students;

    public College(String clgId, String clgName, String clgCity, List<Student> students) {
        this.clgId = clgId;
        this.clgName = clgName;
        this.clgCity = clgCity;
        this.students = students;
    }

    public College(String clgId, String clgName, String clgCity) {
        this.clgId = clgId;
        this.clgName = clgName;
        this.clgCity = clgCity;
    }
   
    // getter and setter
}

public class Student {
    private Long stId;
    private String stName;
    private String stEmail;
    private String clgId;

    public Student(Long stId, String stName, String stEmail, String clgId) {
        super();
        this.stId = stId;
        this.stName = stName;
        this.stEmail = stEmail;
        this.clgId = clgId;
    }

    // getter and setter
}
```

*College Controller*

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/college")
public class CollegeController {
    @Autowired
    private CollegeService collegeService;

    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{clgId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<College> getColleges(@PathVariable("clgId") String clgId) {
        College college = collegeService.getCollege(clgId);
        List student = restTemplate.getForObject("http://student-service/college/student/" + college.getClgId(),
                List.class);
        college.setStudents(student);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(college);
    }
}
```

*application.yml*

```
server:
  port: 9001
  
spring:
  application:
    name: college-service
    
eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: localhost
```

#### Student Service

*Student Controller*
*Entity*

```
public class Student {
    private Long stId;
    private String stName;
    private String stEmail;
    private String clgId;

    public Student(Long stId, String stName, String stEmail, String clgId) {
        super();
        this.stId = stId;
        this.stName = stName;
        this.stEmail = stEmail;
        this.clgId = clgId;
    }

    // getter and setter
}
```

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/college")
public class StudentCotroller {

    @Autowired
    private StudentService studentService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/student/{clgId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<List<Student>> getStudents(@PathVariable("clgId") String clgId) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(studentService.getStudents(clgId));
    }

}
```

*application.yml*

```
server:
  port: 9002
  
spring:
  application:
    name: student-service
    
eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: localhost
```

#### Eureka Server

*application.yml*

```
server:
  port: 8761

eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: localhost
  client:
    registerWithEureka: false
    fetchRegistry: false
  server:
    waitTimeInMsWhenSyncEmpty: 0
```

#### API Gateway Service

*application.yml*

```
server:
  port: 9003
  
eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: localhost

spring:
  application:
    name: api-gateway
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
      - id: college-service
        uri: lb://college-service
        predicates:
        - Path=/college/**
      - id: student-service
        uri: lb://student-service
        predicates:
        - Path=/student/**
```

Comment: `/college/student/CLG01` will always match the college service, not the student service

Comment: @spencergibb What I want to do for match this url for college-service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Predicate for your `student-service` is to match all the requests that start with student(`Path=/student/**`). However you are you calling the `student-service` with the request that starts with college(`/college/student/CLG01`). This request will me matched to `college-service` since you set the predicate for this service as `Path=/college/**`. `/college/**` path matches `/college/student/CLG01` path.

Possible solutions:

1. Change your `StudentController` request mapping from `/college` to `/student`
2. Use different predicate for your student service, such as `Host`
3. Set specific path predicate and change the order of routes:

```
     routes:
      - id: student-service
        uri: lb://student-service
        predicates:
        - Path=/college/student/**
      - id: college-service
        uri: lb://college-service
        predicates:
        - Path=/college/**
```

Comment: Just wanted one clarification if from college controller i remove the request mapping at class level i.e. /college and in spring route definition for college service i keep the predicate path the same as /college/** then also the requests relative to path /college will be directed to college ms .For ex http://localhost:9003/college/1 will be directed to http://localhost:9001/1

Comment: @-Elyorbek could you please provide your comments on above query ?

Comment: Could someone please comments on the above observation

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. After trying a lot things, I found thaat the issue was a dependency problem in the API Gateway.

This is bad:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway-mvc</artifactId>        
    <version>4.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

This is correctly:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>        
    <version>4.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Note don't had the last one dosen't have the "-mvc".

Answer (score 1):

In your build.gradle file
change the dependency from

```
implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-gateway-mvc'
```

to

```
implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-gateway'
```